# GroupByUntilChanged: is there a LINQ GroupBy operator that groups by SUCCESSIVE equal keys?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

As I understand it, the LINQ (to enumerable) operator(s) `GroupBy` will enumerate the whole source sequence before returning the first grouping.
This is not very big data friendly and unnecessary if I know the keys are sorted or if I'm not concerned about having distinct grouping keys.

Is there an operator that I've missed which only groups successive items of the same key and returns a grouping as soon as a new key shows up?

Because I didn't find out how to achieve this with existing functionality I wrote my own operator and called it `GroupByUntilChanged`. Still would prefer to use framework code.

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Groups SUCCESSIVE elements of a sequence having the same key [...].
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupByUntilChanged<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
        if (elementSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elementSelector));

        return GroupByUntilChangedEnumerator(source, keySelector, elementSelector, comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    // omitted: 7 more overloads returning GroupByUntilChangedEnumerator

    private static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupByUntilChangedEnumerator<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
        IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext())
                yield break;
            var grouping = new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(keySelector(e.Current), elementSelector(e.Current));
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var key = keySelector(e.Current);
                if (comparer.Equals(grouping.Key, key))
                    grouping.Add(elementSelector(e.Current));
                else
                {
                    yield return grouping;
                    grouping = new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(key, elementSelector(e.Current));
                }
            }
            yield return grouping;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="IGrouping{TKey, TElement}"/> implementation.
    /// </summary>
    private sealed class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
    {
        private readonly IList<TElement> _elements;

        public Grouping(TKey key, TElement first)
        {
            Key = key;
            _elements = new List<TElement> { first };
        }

        public TKey Key { get; }

        public void Add(TElement next)
        {
            _elements.Add(next);
        }

        public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _elements.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _elements.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw my first stackoverflow question!

Comment: You haven't missed anything, there is no such standard operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard `System.Linq` extension. However, I did find it in [`MoreLinq.MoreEnumerable.GroupAdjacent`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs). In particular, the source is very close to what you have (copying and pasting for posterity):

```
    private static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupAdjacentImpl<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        Debug.Assert(source != null);
        Debug.Assert(keySelector != null);
        Debug.Assert(elementSelector != null);
        Debug.Assert(comparer != null);

        using (var iterator = source.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TElement>(keySelector(item), elementSelector(item)))
                                    .GetEnumerator())
        {
            var group = default(TKey);
            var members = (List<TElement>) null;

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                var item = iterator.Current;
                if (members != null && comparer.Equals(group, item.Key))
                {
                    members.Add(item.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (members != null)
                        yield return CreateGroupAdjacentGrouping(group, members);
                    group = item.Key;
                    members = new List<TElement> { item.Value };
                }
            }

            if (members != null)
                yield return CreateGroupAdjacentGrouping(group, members);
        }
    }

    private static Grouping<TKey, TElement> CreateGroupAdjacentGrouping<TKey, TElement>(TKey key, IList<TElement> members)
    {
        Debug.Assert(members != null);
        return Grouping.Create(key, members.IsReadOnly ? members : new ReadOnlyCollection<TElement>(members));
    }

    static class Grouping
    {
        public static Grouping<TKey, TElement> Create<TKey, TElement>(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> members)
        {
            return new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(key, members);
        }
    }

    #if !NO_SERIALIZATION_ATTRIBUTES
    [Serializable]
    #endif
    private sealed class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<TElement> _members;

        public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> members)
        {
            Debug.Assert(members != null);
            Key = key;
            _members = members;
        }

        public TKey Key { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _members.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

While this is not framework code it is still well written and tested code ([tests](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq.Test/GroupAdjacentTest.cs)) from a library that I've at least seen used by C# developers I respect.